# Django EmailBackend ConnectionRefusedError from app on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere, reset-password

My password reset feature was working fine in development, sending a password reset email, but now that I have deployed to PythonAnywhere, I am getting a ConnectionRefusedError, specifically:

> ConnectionRefusedError at /reset_password
> [Errno 111] Connection refused
> Request Method: POST
> Django Version: 4.1
> Exception Type: ConnectionRefusedError
> Exception Value:
> [Errno 111] Connection refused
> Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/socket.py, line 833, in create_connection
> Raised during:  django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView
> Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
> Python Version: 3.10.5
> Python Path:
> ['/var/www',
> '.',
> '',
> '/var/www',
> '/usr/local/lib/python310.zip',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.10',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
> '/home/gridsquid/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages',
> '/home/gridsquid/gridsquid']
> Server time:    Sat, 12 Nov 2022 16:45:30 +0000

I have verified the user is a valid user with a working email address.

in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'apikey' # Name for all the SenGrid accounts
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
```

in urls.py

```
path("reset_password",
    auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="gridsquid/reset-password.html"),
    name="password_reset"),
path("reset_password_sent",
    auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="gridsquid/reset-password-sent.html"),
    name="password_reset_done"),
path("reset/<uidb64>/<token>",
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="gridsquid/reset.html"),
    name="password_reset_confirm"),
path("reset_password_complete",
    auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="gridsquid/reset-password-complete.html"),
    name="password_reset_complete"),
```

Again, everything is working in my development environment. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Free accounts cannot send smtp email from PythonAnywhere